# how to display entity on autocad drawing area without add to database?

Tags: c#, autocad

I want to display entities on a drawing area as a preview for the user, then if the user accepts the program, add the the entities to the database or make some modification.

I'm used to use transaction and commit the transaction the entities appear if i can make the entities appear before commit the transaction

```
using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    BlockTable bt = tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
    BlockTableRecord btr = tr.GetObject(bt[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;
    int i = poly2TxtSetting.currentFormat.IndexFormat.startWith;
    List<ObjectId> ListTextId = new List<ObjectId>();
    List<ObjectId> ListPointId = new List<ObjectId>();
    foreach (var po in Points)
    {
        i += poly2TxtSetting.currentFormat.IndexFormat.step;
        DBText dtext = new DBText();
        dtext.TextString = i.tostring();
        dtext.Position = po;

        dtext.SetDatabaseDefaults();
        DBPoint point = new DBPoint(po);

        btr.AppendEntity(dtext);
        tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(dtext, true);

        btr.AppendEntity(point);
        tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(point, true);

    }
    tr.Commit();
}
```

Comment: You might be able to use a jig to accomplish this.

Comment: have you seen this [link](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2008/03/using-autocad-2.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for the graphics flush:

```
 tr.TransactionManager.QueueForGraphicsFlush();
```

then prompt for input so the user has time to see the update:

```
PromptKeywordOptions pko = new PromptKeywordOptions("\nKeep Changes?");
pko.AllowNone = true;
pko.Keywords.Add("Y");
pko.Keywords.Add("N");
pko.Keywords.Default = "Y";

PromptResult pkr = ed.GetKeywords(pko);
if (pkr.StringResult == "Y") {
    tr.Commit();
} else {
    tr.Abort();
}
```

This [link](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/transactions/) provides an example application using this technique.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display your model in AutoCAD model space, you have two options.

1) Insert it into database.
2) Add it into Transient Manager.

I think you need is 2nd option.

Search for Transient Graphics.

Check below Code that will help you.

```
Solid3d solid=new Solid(0);
solid.CreateSphere(10);
TransientManager.CurrentTransientManager.AddTransient(solid, TransientDrawingMode.Main, 128, new IntegerCollection());
```

This will display sphere on origin with radius=10;

Comment: fyi this doesn't work in the 2D Wireframe Visual Mode.

Comment: Thats issue with autocad gfx, cant help :(

Comment: try just Wiireframe instead